# Can you apply for a Schengen visa to write an exam?

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas

I am an Indian. I have been selected to take a written test in a German University. Passing it is a requirement for receiving admission. Since I don't have a letter of admission yet, I cannot get a National Visa so I would like to know if a tourist Schengen visa can be obtained to take the exam and return.

Comment: A Schengen visa isn't a tourist visa. You can in principle apply for it for any purpose including taking a test. I don't know whether it would be easy or what the German consulate might require for this but legally there is no obstacle.

Answer (score 2):

The Visum zur Studienbewerbung (student applicant visa) would seem to suit your circumstances and purpose of travel.

> If you don’t have a confirmation of admission from your university yet, you should apply for this visa. It will give you three months in Germany to either wait for the confirmation or to apply for further universities, until you get into one of them. It can be extended for another three months, in case you need more time. Once you get admitted, you can apply for a student visa.

Source: https://www.settle-in-berlin.com/germany-visa/student-visa-germany-application/

Instead of the letter of acceptance, you need to provide the proof of application to a study programme and/or proof of correspondence with the university

Comment: That's a visa for up to 9 months (see e.g. https://taipei.diplo.de/tw-de/-/2451606). Do you know if it would actually be issued for a short visit? I wouldn't rule it out but in the logic of the Schengen system, it would make more sense for that to be covered by a Schengen visa.

Comment: I have looked into that too. The problem is that I can't find that visa-type when I was trying to book an appointment in their website (which is vfs global in my case). It only gives me the option to apply for a regular D-National Visa.

Comment: @SaiPhani Have you tried contacting VFS’ live chat https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/deu/contact-us?

Comment: @Traveller Yes. They too have said that they cannot advise about which visa to take and told me to refer the consulate's website for details regarding or to contact them. When I mailed the consulate, they just replied asking me to again visit their website for more information.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer by Traveler for the better option.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/182187/27650)

Yes, you can apply for a Schengen tourist visa for taking a written test in Germany. Whether you get one depends on convincing the visa officials that you need to be in Germany for the test and that you will return home after the test, which will not be taken as a given.

As you plan to return to Germany a short time later to study you will not be able to show strong ties to your home country.
On top of that comes that a return ticket to Germany is very expensive for just a test.

My advice is to communicate with the university to ask advice, they will have seen the problem more often and may have an alternative for travelling all the way to them for the test. Or they may know how to apply for the right visa.

Comment: One typical solution is to have the exam be proctored by some institution the German university trusts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the university mentioned that they cannot provide help regarding visa doubts. As for the exam, they have mentioned that it can only be taken in the allotted time in their campus and that it cannot be postponed or be written anywhere else.
So I have prepared to travel twice, despite the added costs and hassle.

Comment: If you don’t have it already, get the university to confirm in writing that the exam can only be taken in their campus, and submit that with your application.

Comment: Hello, they have mentioned that condition in mail. That should be sufficient right?